# Try::Tiny: Weird behaviour with try-catch or Not?

Tags: perl, exception, try-catch, cpan, weak-typing

I am using `Try::Tiny` for try-catch.

Code goes as below:

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    print "In try";
    wrongsubroutine();  # undefined subroutine
}
catch {
    print "In catch";
}

somefunction();
```

...

```
sub somefunction {
    print "somefunction";
}
```

When I execute
It comes like this:

```
somefunction
In Try
In catch
```

The output sequence looks wrong to me. Is it wrong? or Is this normal behavior?

Comment: the try part is evaled, so when something goes wrong there, it "dies" and then you get to that catch block because $@ is valid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just like forgetting a semi-colon in

```
print
somefunction();
```

causes the output `somefunction` to be passed to `print` instead of `$_`, a missing semi-colon is causing the output of `somefunction` to be passed as an argument to `catch`.

```
try {
   ...
}
catch {
   ...
};      <--------- missing
somefunction();
```

---

`try` and `catch` are subroutines with the `&@` prototype. That means

```
try { ... } LIST
catch { ... } LIST
```

is the same as

```
&try(sub { ... }, LIST)
&catch(sub { ... }, LIST)
```

So your code is the same as

```
&try(sub { ... }, &catch(sub { ... }, somefunction()));
```

As you can see, the missing semi-colon after the `catch` block is causing `somefunction` to be called before `catch` (which returns an object that tells `try` what to do on exception) and `try`.

The code should be

```
&try(sub { ... }, &catch(sub { ... })); somefunction();
```

which is achieved by placing a semi-colon after the try-catch call.

Comment: Thanks.That was really helpful. I didn't know that there is `;` needed after catch block. +1.

Comment: Also here's a curiosity? Why didn't it complain or raised a syntax error saying semicolon missing.

Comment: @Drt, Are you suggesting `print somefunction();` should be a syntax error because you might have meant `print; somefunction();`? I explained in detail why it's perfectly legal syntax.

Comment: This is so Perlcore!

Answer (score 2):

What sequence do you expect? Does your code really miss the semicolon after the `catch` code?

Comment: Looks like you are right - `somefunction()` would be the last argument of `catch { ... }` (not separate statement) if semicolon was omitted.